# how to combine two filter query in mysql result array and encode json code in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This query have name table and keyword . First query result for name and their relationship table. Second query result for keyword and their relationship table.
I want to combine this statement in one line and then result with JSON encode.

```
$query1[] = $this->search_model->get_filter_name($data); 
$query2[] = $this->search_model->get_filter_keyword($data);
$query = array_merge($query1,$query2);
json_encode($query);
```

Priority, first is name result and second is keyword result.

Comment: With the $query1[] you are adding and array to an array. I think you have to remove these brackets, and define the $queries as arrays with $query = [];

Comment: Thank . I got it when i removed brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove bracket from varibable query  as below .

```
$query1 = $this->search_model->get_filter_name($data); 
$query2 = $this->search_model->get_filter_keyword($data);
$query = array_merge($query1,$query2);
json_encode($query);
```